# Planning of work with taking into account resource availability (MS Project)

Tags: ms-project

I have the following situation in my organization:

Some developers are assigned to Project A. Since this project is currently in the final stage of maintenance (bug corrections, etc.) their involvement in this project declines over time (for example: in February 80%, in March 60%, in April 40%, etc.).

In parallel, I'm planning another Project B, and I would like to be able to do some rough planning of tasks in this project for these developers, taking into account their involvement in Project A.

So for example, Person A is available for 50% in first 5 days of February so when I plan a task that takes 5 working days to complete and starts on the 1st working day of February, MS Project should plan that the completion date of this task will be 8th working day of February.

Unfortunately, it seems like MS Project 2007 doesn't allow for that. I tried to configure "Resource availability" on "Resource sheet" (February 20%, in March 40%, in April 60%, etc.); however, when I create the task, enter "Work" parameter and assign it to a person with variable "Resource availability" configured, it seems like it is not taken into account.

Can anybody confirm whether there is a way in MS Project to achieve the desired outcome?

Comment: Off topic, please close.

Comment: this is not off topic. It's a question about a PM tool.

Comment: Michal, are you using a Master Resource pool for the resources?  Are the projects in separate Project files?  Is there a Master Project plan?  Or are the project files completely isolated? thx

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the task is fixed units instead of fixed work or fixed duration.  If not, it will just make the resource over utilized.  I think the default is fixed work.

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes it's not worth the effort to get MSProject to fine tune this level of resource work. For a short time period I just use my brain and keep track to make sure no one is really over booked. That said, if you do need to manage your resources to a fine level of detail, David's solution is the way I would do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can switch to MS Project Server, you should be able to have a more complete view of resource availability.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, it seems like MS Project 2007 doesn't allow for that. I tried to configure "Resource availability" on "Resource sheet" (February 20%, in March 40%, in April 60%, etc.); however, when I create the task, enter "Work" parameter and assign it to a person [dia chi nang mui dang tin cay](http://www.vienphauthuat.com/dia-chi-nang-mui-dang-tin-cay.html) with variable "Resource availability" configured, it seems like it is not taken into account.